# Using Z3 to return model with least value

Tags: z3

I thought I read somewhere that Z3 has some option for returning the model with the "least" value eg given something like

```
x >= 2
```

Z3 would return 2. I could swear that I saw some reference to this recently, but I am unable to find it now. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

No, Z3 does not produce 'least' models. However, a separate branch of Z3 that adds optimization features is being developed at the moment (the branch is called `opt'), and perhaps will later be integrated into Z3 proper. A tutorial for the current optimization features is available here: [Z3Opt Guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Opt/tutorial/guide)